# Find previous div of a specific class with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use jquery and I want to find the previous div which has the "error" class

My html code :

```
<table class="questions">
    <tr>
        <td class="heading">1
            <div class="error"></div>
        </td>

        <td colspan="4">
            <textarea class="textcontrol required" name='questionT136'>
            </textarea>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td></td>

        <th><label for="reponse137-3">Très satisfaisant</label></th>
        <th><label for="reponse137-4">Satisfaisant</label></th>
        <th><label for="reponse137-5">Insatisfaisant</label></th>
    </tr>

    <tr class="q">
        <td class="heading">
            2
            <div class="error"></div>
        </td>

        <td class="questionradio"><input class="required" id='reponse137-3'
        name='questionN137' type='radio' value='3'></td>

        <td class="questionradio"><input class="required" id='reponse137-4'
        name='questionN137' type='radio' value='4'></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

For example, from *reponse137-3*, I'd like to change the value the previous class="error". I allready tryied to access to that object with :

```
$('#reponse137-3').prev(".error")
```

but it doesn't work. I think because it hasn't the same parent, so I tryied :

```
$('#reponse137-3').prev("tr").next(".error")
```

How can I do ?

Comment: You forgot the # in your selector.

Comment: well I forgot it because I used jquery validator and I use a direct reference to my element. Sorry for this mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your `.error` div is always in the same table row:

```
$('#reponse137-3').closest('tr').find('.error:first');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vkfF8/

Comment: But it doesn't work if there is more than one element with class `error` in the `tr` element!

Comment: @Samuel Cailerie It works. the <div class="error"></div> is a child of every <tr>

Answer (score 2):

You need to go up three times to arrive to table, and later find error

```
$('#reponse137-3').parent().parent().parent().find('.error');
```

First parent go to th, second to tr and thirth to table, then find within table what element has class named .error And you will get it

Comment: The lookup is not on the `label` but on the `input`.